# Spring more than one profile and ${spring.profiles.active}

Tags: spring

In spring 4.1.2.RELEASE, we have 2 active profiles in web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>Production,Customer1</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And we want to dynamically load some property files as below:

```
<util:properties id="accountPolicy"
        location="classpath:/configs/${spring.profiles.active}/sample.properties" />
```

The `${spring.profiles.active}` is not working, may be because there are two profiles, I tried some lookups like: `${spring.profiles.active[1]}` but no luck !

Any comments

Updated:

It seems that `${spring.profiles.active}` is an comma seperated list I try below:

```
<util:properties id="signConditions"
        location="classpath:/configs/#{ {'${spring.profiles.active}'.split(',')}.get(1) }/sample.properties" />
```

But the error seems that there will be an XML parsser error:

```
    org.springframework.expression.ParseException: 
Expression 'classpath:/configs/#{ {'Production,Customer1'.split('' @ 19: No ending suffix '}' for expression starting at character 19: #{ {'Production,Customer1'.split('
```

Comment: may sound trivial but did you tried with single profile?

Comment: yes I tried, it seems that ${spring.profiles.active} is an arrayList and must be splited

Comment: ok.. think you need to check with `#{spring.profiles.active[1]}` (note the `#` instead of `$`)

Comment: Please see my updated

Comment: #{ {'${spring.profiles.active}'}.split(',')}  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This did the job:

```
<util:properties id="signConditions"
        location="classpath:/configs/#{environment.getActiveProfiles()[1]}/sample.properties" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the more proper way is to do something like:

```
<beans profile="Production">
    <!-- some other stuff for Production profile -->
</beans>

<beans profile="Customer1">
    <util:properties id="accountPolicy"
        location="classpath:/configs/Customer1/sample.properties" />
    <!-- some other stuff for Customer1 profile -->
</bean>
```

Profiles are supposed to be used as Profiles of configurations in app context, instead of like a property for replacement (as what you are doing)

---

Edit base on my comment:

What you are looking for is not a proper use case of Spring profile feature (at least not now).  What you are trying to do is having property place holder work base on a system property.  However, activation of profiles can be done through other way.  Which means, you can turn on a profile without that `spring.profiles.active` system property.  What you are doing is not reliable.

If it is fine for you to pass in system properties, why not do something like:

1. Have a profile called `Customer`, which denote for deployment to customers which will involve account policy (and other stuff)
2. Pass in a system property, for example, with key = 'customerCode' and value being an identifier for a customer.

By doing so, what you need to do is

```
<beans profile="Production">
    <!-- some other stuff for Production profile -->
</beans>

<beans profile="Customer">
    <util:properties id="accountPolicy"
        location="classpath:/configs/${customerCode}/sample.properties" />
    <!-- some other stuff for Customer1 profile -->
</bean>
```

and system properties you need for your application should looks like: `-Dspring.profiles.active="Production,Customer" -DcustomerCode=Customer1`

Then you have proper use of profiles, and no need to duplicate `accountPolicy` for each customer.

Comment: Yes, But the problem is that I should repeat this line for every user `<util:properties id="accountPolicy" location="classpath:/configs/Customer1/sample.properties" />`. Did you review the error which is about xml parsing ?

Comment: But what you are trying to do is simply property place holder base on the system property of active profile. However, there are other way activating profiles WITHOUT that system property. What you are trying to do is simply putting yourself into future pitfall. What you are trying to do is not an appropriate use case for profile (at least not for the current profile feature provided by Spring)

Comment: Just have a property for Customer code, and have a single line doing that Customer Sample property file. Then it is just a matter of passing in customer code thru system property, which is not anything harder than what you are currently trying to do.